# Escaping issue in building query dynamic function variables

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, function, activerecord

I am developing a CMS which works on template page system in a different approach.

I have this object:

```
$structure = new stdClass;

$structure->homepage->news->method            = 'get_articles_by_page_name';
$structure->homepage->news->lang_key          = translate('home_news');
$structure->homepage->news->lang              = $lang;
$structure->homepage->news->add_media         = true;
$structure->homepage->news->media_type        = 'ibs';
$structure->homepage->news->limit             = '5';
$structure->homepage->news->order_by          = 'a.logical_date';
$structure->homepage->news->asc_des           = 'desc';
$structure->homepage->news->result_type       = 'result';
```

This helps to get contents as following:

```
foreach ($structure as $page_template => $page_contents)
{
  // Call Customized Content for Homepage
  if($this->data['page_data']->page_view == $page_template) // homepage comes ok.
  {
    foreach ($page_contents as $view_var_name => $page_cdata)
    {
      $method = $page_cdata->method; // method names comes
      $page_cdata = substr(implode(",",(array) $page_cdata),(strlen($method)+1)) . '\'';
      //Returns as expected:
      //**'Haberler','tr','1','ibs','5','a.logical_date','desc','result'**

      $this->data[$view_var_name] = $this->publish->$method($page_cdata);
      vdebug($page_cdata);
    }
  }
}
```

It suppose to call them model function of:

```
function get_articles_by_page_name( $lang_key='',$lang='en',$add_media=true,
 media_type='ibs',$limit='0',$order_by='a.logical_date',$asc_desc='desc',$result_type='result')
```

However, there is a problem with. When I return to last worked query it says:

```
SELECT * FROM (`page`) JOIN `page_lang` ON `page`.`id_page` = `page_lang`.`id_page` WHERE `page_lang`.`title` = '\'News\',\'tr\',\'1\',\'ibs\',\'5\',\'a.logical_date\',\'desc\',\'result\''
```

It souldn't be like this. every thing between commas are parameters of the method function. What cause this, any idea?

Content of get_articles_by_page_name:

```
function get_articles_by_page_name ($lang_key='',$lang='tr',$add_media=true,$media_type='ibs',$limit='0',$order_by='a.logical_date',$asc_desc='desc',$result_type='result')
{
  // Define variables
  $id_page    = ''; 
  $result     = '';

  // Get Page Data
  $page_name    = $lang_key;
  $get_page     = $this->vayes->getJoined('page','page_lang','id_page','','',array('page_lang.title'=>$page_name),'row');
  if($get_page)
  {
    $id_page  = $get_page->id_page;
    $result   = $this->publish->get_articles($lang,$id_page,null,false,'',$order_by,$asc_desc,$limit,'result');
  }
  else
  {
    $result = array('No id_page specified');
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Content of get_articles:

```
function get_articles($lang='tr',$id_page,$id_article=null,$incl_media=true,$media_type='',$order_by='a.logical_date',$asc_desc='desc',$limit='0',$result_type='result')
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('article a');
  $this->db->join('article_lang b','b.id_article=a.id_article','left outer');

  if($incl_media) {
    $this->db->join('article_media c','c.id_article=b.id_article','left outer');
    $this->db->join('media d','d.id_media=c.id_media','left outer'); 
  }

  if($id_article == null) { $this->db->where('a.id_page',$id_page); }
  else /*------------->*/ { $this->db->where('a.id_article',$id_article); }

  $this->db->where('b.lang',$lang);
  $this->db->where('b.online',1);

  if(($incl_media == true) AND $media_type != '' ) $this->db->where('c.usage',$media_type);

  // Order Results
  $this->db->order_by($order_by,$asc_desc);

  // Limit Results
  if ($limit) $this->db->limit($limit);

  $query = $this->db->get();

  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    $result = $query->$result_type();
    $query->free_result();
    return $result;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for tidy-up question writing.

Comment: Please post the contents of `get_articles_by_page_name`

Comment: You are imploding the entitery of the $page_cdata "array" without filtering non-data parts.

Comment: @MarcB, which non-data parts?

Comment: $page_cdata becomes a monolithic string, which you pass to your dynamic method. for that sort of thing to work, you'd have to eval() that code instead. and eval() is evil.

Comment: @MarcB I checked eval(), even in manual it says don't use it unless it is deadly required. So, is there any other way to go to the solution for me?

Comment: Recode your methods to accept a single array for the arguments?

Comment: @MarcB I have added to method `$page_cdata = array();
    if(is_array($lang_key)) 
    {
      $page_cdata = $lang_key;
      unset($page_cdata['method']);
      foreach ($lang_key as $param_name => $param_value)
      {
        $$param_name = $param_value;
      }
    }` and it works thank you.

Comment: you could probably avoid the foreach loop by using extract().

Comment: @MarcB I love extract function. Thank you fy guidance. If you put this info as answer below, I'd love to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Attempting to use stripslashes on an array in 5.2.17 returns the string "Array", but in 5.3.6 it returns NULL. So using stripslashes() on an array you will need to do it recursively;

```
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example
$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

// Output
print_r($array);
```